# Maven FTP repository

Tags: ftp, repository, maven-3

I have setup a maven repository on my webserver using FTP.

The deployment works as expected, but when I wnat to install a submodule it does not find the files on the webserver, because it is trying to download from a wrong location.

I have setup the maven repo with a folder for snapshots and one for releases:

```
/ftp-dir/
  releases/
  snapshots/
```

The root pom file has fllowing distributionManagement:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
    <id>repo-id</id>
        <url>ftp://my-ftp/releases</url>
    </repository>
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>develman.repository</id>
    <url>ftp://my-ftp/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

If I run mvn deploy with a -SNAPSHOT version it deploys the files into the snapshots directory as expected.

But when I delete my local repository and try to install a submodule maven cannot find the artifact. My settings.xml looks like this:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>repo-id</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
            <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository-id</id>
            <name>my repository</name>
                    <url>http://my-website-address.com</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

aven tries to download from http://my-website-address.com/... and not from http://my-website-address.com/snapshots as expected.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my repositories definition to two seperate repositories (1 for snapshot, 1 for release):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>repository-release-id</id>
                <name>my release repository</name>
                <url>http://my-website-address.com/releases</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>repository-snapshot-id</id>
                <name>my snapshot repository</name>
                <url>http://my-website-address.com/snapshots</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```